# Geolocation package in ubuntu for python

Tags: python, ubuntu

How to install geolocation package in ubuntu for python?

I want to get data using geolocation like city, postalcode, etc.

how to get city, country using postal code, would please you suggest me any library

Comment: try to look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543018/what-python-libraries-can-tell-me-approximate-location-and-timezone-given-an-ip

Answer (score 0):

This might be of some use: http://www.hostip.info/use.html 
It is an IP geolocation website with an API you could use in python. It may not be very accurate though.

Comment: how to get city, country using postal code, would you suggest me any library

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get install geoip-bin
$ geoiplookup 8.8.8.8
GeoIP Country Edition: US, United States
```

If you need only the database, without tools:

```
$ sudo apt-get install geoip-database
```